# How can I specify a specific channel to set B&C for in FIJI?

Tags: imagej, fiji

I've written a primative FIJI script which opens up my 16-bit 3 channel images and allows me to crop regions of interest. However, I can't figure out how to **set the brightness and contrast automatically**. At the moment I have to do this manually by having the picture open, moving the slider to the second channel, then setting min and max. I tried to use setMinAndMax(98, 2696); but this applied it to my first channel, not my second. Can't find any info on specifying which channel other than using setMinAndMax(98, 2696, 2); - but that only works on RGB images it seems.

Here is my code:

````
outputDir = inputDir + "montage_cropped" + File.separator;
File.makeDirectory(outputDir);

list = getFileList(inputDir);

for (i = 0; i < lengthOf(list); i++) {
    if (endsWith(list[i], ".tif")) {
        open(inputDir + list[i]);

waitForUser("Adjust brightness and contrast for the second channel and click OK when done.", "");

// Draw a rectangle
makeRectangle(3000, 6720, 1000, 1000);

// Wait for user to move the rectangle
waitForUser("Select the CROP region", "Drag the crop ROI to the desired location, then click <<OK>>");

run("Duplicate...", "duplicate");
run("RGB Color");

// Generate output file name
        cropName = replace(list[i], ".tif", "_crop.tif");

        // Save the cropped image
        saveAs("Tiff", outputDir + cropName);

close();
close();
        close();
    }
}```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Tried setMinAndMax(98, 2696, 2); but this only works for RGB images.
````

Comment: You can add `Stack.setChannel(2); // set to second channel` before your first `waitForUser()` command